# How I can keep all my mysql database work even after reinstalling Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, lamp

I'm new Ubuntu user. I'm confused about `/var` mount point related issue.
Currently I'm using 3 partitions on my 500GB HDD. `/` 50GB, `/home` 392.* GB and `swap` 15 GB. All I found after searching over internet that data on `/home` will be kept. But didn't found any article if it will keep `/var` even after reinstalling or upgrading Ubuntu. The main issue is I want to be safe all my created mysql database. It would be great pleasure for me if you can suggest me how to keep it safe or will it make safe if I create separate `/var` partition? I'm using single boot.

May be this is very basic question but it's big for me.
And sorry for my bad English (trying to improve )
Thanks in advanced.
Md Al Amin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `/var` will be deleted, if you install Ubuntu again, because `/var` is not on a separate partition and probably it's a good idea to create a separate partition for `/var`.

Make a backup of `/var` and move your databases back after the re-installation of Ubuntu.

From the comments, an important point:

> Make sure that the MySQL server is stopped before copying the contents
>   of /var otherwise your backup might get incomplete.

I make a backup of `/etc`, `/var` and `/opt` if I re-install my system.

Comment: Thanks. I was confused about it. Another thing, Is there any was to keep my manual installed applications?

Comment: Your applications you should reinstall. An exception, in my opinion, `/opt`.

Comment: Something important about the backup - make sure that the MySQL server is stopped before copying the contents of /var otherwise your backup might get incomplete.

Comment: @SledgeHammer Good point.

Comment: Thanks. I understand how to make backup of mysql. And thanks for the point @SledgeHammer

Answer (score 2):

Before you reinstall your system, move the mySQL databases to `/home` and then forget about any complicated stuff from now on!

```
sudo service mysql stop
sudo cp --recursive --preserve=all /var/lib/mysql/ /home/
```

Then:

```
sudo nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

and set `datadir` to `/home/mysql`

```
sudo nano /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld
```

add:

```
/home/mysql/ r,
/home/mysql/** rwk,
```

then:

```
apparmor_parser -r /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld
sudo service mysql start
```

After you've verified it all works, just delete `/var/lib/mysql`

Comment: Don't thank me!  **;-)** If you like my answer, just click the little grey **☑** under the "0" now turning it into beautiful green.  If you do not like my answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the 0, and if you *really* like my answer, click on the little grey checkmark *and* the little up-arrow...  If you have any further questions, go to http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask

Comment: Very nice explanation. I bookmarked this page because of your answer (I know I've to use it) but I don't have enough repo to up vote :(

Comment: Just clicking the little **☑** is good enough, unless the other answer is better, then just don't do anything!  **;-)**

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution to use:

> create a new partition to /var

1. create a new partition to hold /var. you can use [Gparted](http://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=help-manual) to do that.
2. Create the filesystems for this partitions (can be done with Gparted too) or use

   ```
   mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdaX
   ```

   replace X with your own partition number for the newly created
3. Mount the new filesystem under /mnt

   ```
   mkdir /mnt/var        
   mount /dev/sdaX /mnt/var
   ```
4. Go to single-user mode so that there is no rw activity on the directory

   ```
   init 1
   ```
5. Enter your root password
6. Backup data in /var

   ```
   cd /var
   cp -ax * /mnt/var
   ```
7. Rename the /var directory after your data has been transferred
   successfully

   ```
   cd /
   mv var var.BAK
   ```
8. Make the new var directory

   ```
   mkdir var
   ```
9. Unmount the new partition

   ```
   umount /dev/sdaX
   ```
10. Remount it as /var

    ```
    mount /dev/sdaX /var
    ```
11. Edit /etc/fstab file to include the new partition, with /var being
     the mount point, so that it will be automatically mounted at boot.

    ```
    /dev/sdaX       /var     ext4    defaults    0 0
    ```

[All credential goes to source](http://blog.oshim.net/2011/10/how-to-move-var-folder-to-new-partition.html)

Now you have your /var on single partition so you don't have to take care about loosing data when reinstalltion.